# When should I decide to use Sprite over Texture and vice versa?

Tags: libgdx

Say I have a main menu screen which has a Logo which is png. Would I draw it as a texture or convert it into a sprite then draw it? This logo would have no interactivity on it, it's just sitting there looking pretty.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest using Scene2D Image for a Menu logo since it is easier to integrate with the rest of the menu (using layouts/tables and the like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you which you prefer. Sprite is a convenience class that allows a Texture or TextureRegion store its position, rotation and scale, etc. If you don't use Sprite, that just means you plan to store that info elsewhere to use when you call `draw()`.

Typically, you should try to put a groups of 2D images into a single TextureAtlas using TexturePacker, from which you can extract TextureRegions or Sprites (which are TextureRegions with features) to draw as a batch with SpriteBatch. If you only have a couple images on screen, such as on the initial loading screen, then you might want to go with just a Texture, but generally, you want to minimize the number of unique Textures on screen at once for performance reasons.

For instance, the low-res 2D game I'm working on has only three image files. One is the logo that appears before anything else is loaded, so I just draw it as a Texture, centered on screen. The other two are TextureAtlases, containing hundreds of sprites. One that is loaded with nearest filtering, and the other that is loaded with linear filtering.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Also, if I have a set of images that are in scale with each other, but are tiny. Would it be best to draw everything at their native scale in a tiny little screen, or should I change the size of the window in the DesktopLauncher class and then upscale all my textures manually when i create them?

Comment: A lot of factors that should affect that decision. Not enough room to answer in comments.